# Kendo Q3 2013 grid scrolling not working

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When I upgraded to Q3 2013, the grid stopped displaying my data.  I'm retrieving this data using the transport Read URL (which generates an ajax read request to the server).

Comment: Above just an FYI - it's own answer

Comment: It is fine to answer your own questions, but could you rephrase your post to be more like a question? You can then answer it using the answer box below.

Answer (score 1):

With Q3, the Kendo grid w/ virtual now requires the Total property to be returned (a simple number indicating how many rows are in the returned data set).  If you use Kendo's `ToDataSourceResult(request)` method to return a dataset, this is automatically provided for you.  We don't use that method, because it requires our web service to take a `DataSourceRequest` parameter, which is functionality that our web services don't wish to guarantee for the future.  Thus our web service operation now returns the following object:

```
public class DataCollection
{
    public ICollection Data { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```